# How to parse JSON string not object

Tags: json, sql-server

There is a `VARCHAR` column `jsonString` that has simple text that is formatted as JSON:

```
id         jsonString
1          {"topData":{"personName":"john","personAge":"20"}}
2          {"topData":{"personName":"mike","personAge":"30"}}
3          {"topData":{"personName":"sten","personAge":"50"}}
```

How to parse this string? It is not a JSON object, so do we need to cast it as JSON first?

```
select OPENJSON(cast(jsonString as JSON)
```

I have tried many ways but couldn't extract `personName` and `personAge` as separate values.

Comment: Please who us the "many ways" you have tried.

Comment: According to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, "jsonExpression Is a Unicode character expression containing JSON text.". So there is no need to cast your string to anything at all.

Comment: did you suceed at the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT personName,
       personAge 
FROM NAME_OF_THE_TABLE
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (jsonString)
WITH
(
    personName nvarchar(50) '$topData.personName',
    personAge tinyint '$topData.personAge'
)
```

You didn't mention the name of the table, so you can replace the `NAME_OF_THE_TABLE` by the real one